# How to create a value-responsive checkbox in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have a page with a few fields, loaded from a DB table, such as:

```
Name:   John Smith
ID:     jsa44
State:  MA
--Hidden--ActiveUser:yes
```

I want to display a checkbox that is checked when activeuser is yes and unchecked when activeuser is no. Also, I want to change the value of activeuser whenever the checkbox check status changes.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having ActiveUser as a hidden item, make it a Checkbox item with these attributes:
[image]

(Note Display Extra Values set to No).

Then add a computation like this:
[image]

(My item was called P1_X).  This computation handles the fact that the unchecked value of a checkbox is always NULL, converting that to 'no'.